# How to create/change a theme at runtime

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to implement a custom theme selector. That mean
choosing a color for primary, accent, warn and background, it does not mean selecting a predefined theme.

When the user has changed a color I want to show the effect of the change.
Therefore a part of the DOM with some samples gets an other (md-theme) theme assigned.

I see the following approaches:

- use a theme, say "test" and change the color at runtime.
- register the changes as new theme and dynamically change the themename (md-theme, md-theme-watch)

  However, I have no idea how to make either approaches.

It seems that I could only register themes at startup but that is not what I need

Comment: use app.run(); in your application

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I did a deeper look at the sources (version 1.0.0). So I resulted in following statements

- The first approach will not work. Angular Material compiles a theme only once. Themes will be skipped if already compiled.

  I guess this has been choosen to get a good performance.
- Second approach fails, too. Angular Material gives themed elements a copy of currrent themes. So the elements will not know about newly created themes.

  It is not clear to me which design decision has caused this.

To show how theme changes I decided to use an iframe. In the end I have two pages. When changes apply the page flicker somewhat but that is acceptable

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use $md-theming--provider during application configuration:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
  .primaryPalette('pink', {
      'default': '400', // by default use shade 400 from the pink palette for primary intentions
  'hue-1': '100', // use shade 100 for the <code>md-hue-1</code> class
  'hue-2': '600', // use shade 600 for the <code>md-hue-2</code> class
  'hue-3': 'A100' // use shade A100 for the <code>md-hue-3</code> class
})
// If you specify less than all of the keys, it will inherit from the
// default shades
.accentPalette('purple', {
  'default': '200' // use shade 200 for default, and keep all other shades the same
});
```

});

Here you can copy the default theme, extend a theme or create a new one.

Once the theme is registered you can use it in the entire aplication (all md-theme directives...) with $mdThemingProvider.alwaysWatchTheme(true); (Please note the perfomance issues this aproach could have)

If you need some more info / examples please refer to.

- [Configuring a theme](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme)
- [Multiple themes](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/04_multiple_themes)

Comment: I want to create a theme somewhere in the lifetime of the application, not only at startup. I know the way to define theme during startup